# How can I access the Python command line using PyCharm's console?

Tags: python, pycharm

Trying to get to grips with PyCharm's Python console.

Am looking for a way I can run a `--version` command similar to the one detailed on this page: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#generic-options

I tried in the Python Console at the bottom of PyCharm but it throws me a `NameError: name 'version' is not defined` so I'm guessing it's not the right place to try these kind of commands. I also tried in the Terminal window but it didn't work there either.

Is there another place I can run these commands?

P.s. I now realise the console actually shows me the version number at the top. But actually I want to know how to be able to run these types of commands in general.

Comment: What about `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: Just use the regular Terminal within PyCharm; the Python console isn't the same as the command line.

Comment: Thanks both. I tried running `--version` in the Terminal but it just tells me `'version' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not including the word Python... `--version` is a command line argument for the `python` command, not a command in its own right.

Comment: Ah! perfect, thank you. That works great. I was also in the wrong directory in the terminal which didn't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jonrsharpe - for anyone else wondering you need to:

1. Use the Terminal window
2. (Possibly don't need to do this step) Make sure you're in the right directory (the one containing python.exe)
3. Put `python` before the command line argument

Comment: You shouldn't need to be in the same directory if you've installed Python correctly.

Comment: Ah, maybe I haven't installed it correctly then. Cheers for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Regular terminal and PyCharm terminal are the same. So open the terminal console in PyCharm and type command,

```
python --version
```

Inside the python console (of any PyCharm or regular terminal), you can get the python version as,

```
~ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) \n[GCC 4.8.2]'
```